# How long does it take to empty the vessel?

Tags: word-problem

> Two taps A and B can fill a vessel in 12 and 15 minutes, respectively, but a third pipe C can empty the full tank in 60 minutes. A and B is kept open for 5 minutes in the beginning and then C is also opened. In what time will the vessel be emptied?

Answer:

> 45 minutes

---

Attempted solution:

Portion filled in 5 min by A and B = (1/12 + 1/15)*5 = 9/12.

When  all the three pipes are open, the vessel has to be emptied. So the rate of emptying the vessel should be higher than the rate of filling the vessel. But the rate of emptying the vessel (1/60 portion per minute) is slower than the rate of filling the vessel by taps A and B individually (1/12 th portion per minute and 1/15th portion per minute ). So the tap should fill up instead of getting emptied!

Nevertheless,

Since the tank has to be emptied in lets say time t, we have the following equation:

(1/60 - 1/12 -1/15)*t = 9/12

=>(1-5-4)t/60 = 9/12

which results in a negative t = -45/8 minutes.

Please help me with this. Please correct me if my concept is wrong.

Comment: You are right, if all three pipes A,B,C are operating then the rate going in is larger than the rate out.  But, if you assume you shut off the A and B taps after 5 minutes, so that only C drains out from then on, the answer is 45 minutes.  So likely that is the intended scenario. It is just the time for C to drain 9/12 of the tank.

Comment: 45/8 is a correct answer.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh But time is coming negative!

Comment: No you can see in my answer time is positive.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. When something is empty by a pipe we take its value negative and pipes filling we take their values positive.

Comment: You have to use (1/12 + 1/15 -1/60)*t = 9/12 instead of (1/60 - 1/12 -1/15)*t = 9/12.

Comment: Sir but 9/12 portion has to be "emptied" not filled....When something is emptied by a pipe we take its value negative and pipes filling we take their values positive when the tank has to be filled overall...But here in this case tank has to be emptied not filled...So  the case will be reverse.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh

Comment: I got a solution. Wait I post it.

Comment: My method of doing this question is right. I have the same question in my book. Time taken by C is written wrong in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50539/discussion-between-user3237657-and-kanwaljit-singh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portion filled in 5 min by A and B = $\left(\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{15}\right) * 5 = \frac{9}{12} = \frac{3}{4}$

After 5 minute,

C - A - B = $\left(\frac{1}{60} - \frac{1}{12} - \frac{1}{15}\right)$

= $\frac{-8}{60}$ or $\frac{-2}{15}$

Answer is negative because speed of empty pipe is so slower.

So tank will be not emptying it is filling.

Edit - The question asked by OP has an answer 45 minutes but he is getting answer -45/8 minutes. It means vessel is not emptying. But the above question has some mistake C empty in 6 minutes not 60. So if we do above question using 6 minutes we have correct result 45 minutes (Given below).

Original question -

[image: page 1]

Solution -

[image: page 2]

[image: page 3]

Comment: You are amazing bro. Thank you for helping me with this. May I ask which book you are following. I have taken this question from Pearson Guide to Quantitative Aptitude and Data Interpretation for the CAT. Pg-1.181 . Q.26. Seems like the question is indeed wrong there. Thanks for helping me with this...

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. Would you mind changing A + B - C to C-A-B in your answer so that those viewing this question wont get the same doubt as I did.

Comment: I have taken this pics from R.S Aggarwal (quantative aptitude book). One of the best book for aptitude.

Comment: According to your question it should be A+B-C. Because empty speed is less than filling. And according to book it is C-A-B. As emptying speed is more than filling.

Comment: Now I got the reason why your answer is negative. As empty speed is so slow.

Comment: Yes according to question in my book, It should fill up if all three of them are open as you have rightly said emptying speed is slower. Anyways question in my book seems to be wrong.

Comment: Yes did it..but you wont be able to see it as my reputation is less than 15

Comment: Its ok. Hope this type of questions are now clear to you.

Comment: Sir,Do you have any idea how to solve this using shortcut method? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184648/profit-loss-and-discount

Answer (score 0):

The flow rates are

$$\varphi_A = \frac{1}{12} \,\rm{vpm} \qquad \qquad \qquad \varphi_B = \frac{1}{15} \,\rm{vpm} \qquad \qquad \qquad  \varphi_C = \frac{1}{6} \,\rm{vpm}$$

where $\rm{vpm}$ stands for "vessels per minute". Since $A$ and $B$ are open for $5$ minutes, the following volume of water flows in

$$\left(\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{15}\right) \rm{vpm} \cdot 5 \, \rm{minutes} = \frac 34 \,\rm{vessels}$$

Once valve $C$ is open, the flow rate is

$$\varphi_A + \varphi_B - \varphi_C = - \frac{1}{60} \,\rm{vpm}$$

A negative flow rate tells us that the vessel is emptying. It takes

$$\dfrac{\frac 34 \,\rm{vessels}}{\frac{1}{60} \,\rm{vpm}} = 45 \, \rm{minutes}$$

for the vessel to be emptied.

Comment: If we use value of C as 6 we got answer 45 minutes. But OP uses C = 60.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh The OP must be wrong. If $\varphi_C = \frac{1}{60}$, then $$\varphi_A + \varphi_B - \varphi_C = \frac{2}{15} > 0$$ which means that the tank will **never** empty.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you for answer.