# Profit,Loss and Discount

Tags: word-problem

I want to solve this problem by the shortcut method taught in my class. So it will be highly helpful if somebody knows this method and would resolve my doubt in the shortcut method I have used here.

Q.A shopkieeper sells an article at 12% discount on the marked price and makes a profit of 10%.If he gives a discount of 4% he will earn a profit of Rupees 40. Find the marked price of the article. Correct answer :Rs 250. Where might have I gone wrong?

My Attempt:

CP=Cost Price, SP=Selling Price, MP=Marked Price

[image]

Comment: What's "SP"? What's "CP"? What's "MP"?

Comment: @5xum     SP=Selling Price,CP=Cost Price,MP=Marked Price

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Plz see [the MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189) for typesetting tables on math.SE.
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\mathrm{CP} & \mathrm{SP} & \mathrm{MP} \\ \hline
& 88 &  \\ \hline
10*8 & 11*8 &  \\ \hline
80 & 88 & 100 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your mistake.

96 - 80 = 16. Not 6.

Then you get correct result.

Comment: Sorry for late reply as I was busy.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the article is $v$, and the price of the article (before any discounts) is $p$.

Then,

> A shopkeeper sells an article at 12% discount on the marked price and makes a profit of 10%

tells you that $0.88\cdot p = 1.1\cdot c$

and

> If he gives a discount of 4% he will earn a profit of Rupees 40

Tells you that $0.96 \cdot p = c + 40$

This should be all you need.

Comment: Sir, I know how to do this sum by the method you used. I cant understand what 40 should be equivalent to in the method that I have used, and would like to know how to proceed in that  method.